# Delegating entire website by a certain domain provider hosted in Wix to AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, velo

I have a website where my domain provider is Netfirms. I have created a Wix website and connected the domain and have designed the website on Wix. I want to delegate the entire website to AWS Route 53, making sure that the website shows everything designed on Wix. The steps I believe are:

1. Create AWS Route 53 Hosted zone
2. Create A records and CNAME records (using IP and CNAME Value from Wix)
3. Delete domain on Wix
4. Update Nameservers (removing previous) and adding those from AWS Route 53.

Are the steps correct? If yes, how much time will the website be not working for? On Wix, there are other type of records (TXT and MX), do I have to create those in AWS Route 53 hosted zones, or should that work as it is?

I got the IP address from Wix (there were 3), and I got the CNAME (for www) from Wix, but I do not know if this works.

Comment: IN wix you can not just delete the domain, you will still need to point it. A complete list with all steps can be found here: https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-domain-to-wix-using-the-pointing-method